# Static Variable of Abstract class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, abstract-class, static-variables

Abstract class :

```
public abstract class Datainfo {
public static int loadsameimage = 0 ;
}
```

The button from fragment A

```
Button saveimage = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.quessavebtn);

    saveimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Datainfo.loadsameimage = 1;
            savequesimage();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Answer Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

onResume for fragment B

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {

    if( Datainfo.loadsameimage == 1 )
    setimageaftersavefromquestion();
    Datainfo.loadsameimage = 0;
    }

    super.onResume();
}
```

Problem : cannot change the value of static variable in abstract class (Datainfo) . want to invoke the method (saveimageaftersavefromquestion) when onResume is called. It seems that the value of (Datainfo.loadsameimage) is not change when i pressed the button.

hope someone can help me to understand why is this method wont work. thank you

Comment: Have you tried to place loadsameimage to another class? I mean, problem should not be in "abstract"

Comment: I think the `onClick()` method was never called.

Comment: yeah, that's supposed to work, although I find it baffling that someone would use an `int` to store a `boolean` when using `Java`... Either use an `enum`or a `boolean`.

Comment: onClick() method is called because the savequesimage() inside it is executed successfully.